# Data sent from Tcp Client is received very slowly

Tags: c++, linux, tcp, tcpclient, tcpserver

The system I have to do has one tcp server and about 1000 tcp clients. 
1000 clients will send data to tcp server every second. 
To simulate this situation, At first I connected to tcp server with 50 sockets from a single pc with below code.

```
int main() {

    const char *hello = "Hello from client";

    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(8080);
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.39");

    vector<int> vec;


    for ( uint8_t i = 0; i < 50; i++ ) {

        int sock =  socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        if ( sock < 0 ) {
            cout << "... Cant Allocated Socket\n";
            return -1;
        }

        if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
        {
            cout << "... Connection Failed \n";
            return -1;
        }



        vec.push_back(sock);
    }

    for ( uint8_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++ ) {
        send(vec[i], hello, strlen(hello), 0);
        cout << "Message Send\n";
    }


    for ( uint8_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++ ) {
        shutdown(vec[i], 0);
        close(vec[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

After the tcp clients connect to the tcp server, they send the data to the tcp server and close the socket. I can see from terminal that tcp clients can send packet without waiting(less than 10ms)

The above tcp client code can work successfully and send the data to tcp server successfully.
I show the data from the tcp client with the tcp server code below.

```
#define _DEF_TCP_SERVER_PORT                                        8080
#define _DEF_TCP_SERVER_MAX_QUEUE_LISTEN                            12

bool finish_app = false;

struct TcpClient {
    int clientSocket;
    struct in_addr clientAddr;
};
vector<TcpClient> TcpClients;


struct _ServiceTcpServer {
    bool enable;
    int sock;
    uint16_t connectedClient;
    uint32_t sockLen;
    sockaddr_in tcpServerAddr;
    sockaddr_in remoteAddr;
};

struct _ServiceTcpServer _serviceTcpServer;


void init_tcp_server_socket() {

    _serviceTcpServer.tcpServerAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    _serviceTcpServer.tcpServerAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    _serviceTcpServer.tcpServerAddr.sin_port = htons(_DEF_TCP_SERVER_PORT);
    _serviceTcpServer.sockLen = sizeof(_serviceTcpServer.remoteAddr);

    int flag = 1;

    for ( ;; ) {
        _serviceTcpServer.sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        if ( _serviceTcpServer.sock < 0 ) {
            cout << "... Failed to allocate socket.\n";
            this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));
            continue;
        }

        if ( setsockopt(_serviceTcpServer.sock, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, (char *) &flag, sizeof(int)) ) {
            cout << "... Set SockOpt failed.\n";
            close(_serviceTcpServer.sock);
            this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));
            continue;
        }

        if( bind(_serviceTcpServer.sock, (sockaddr *) &_serviceTcpServer.tcpServerAddr, sizeof(_serviceTcpServer.tcpServerAddr)) == -1 ) {
            cout << "... Socket bind failed.\n";
            close(_serviceTcpServer.sock);
            this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));
            continue;
        }

        if ( listen(_serviceTcpServer.sock, _DEF_TCP_SERVER_MAX_QUEUE_LISTEN) != 0 ) {
            cout << "... Socket listen failed.\n";
            close(_serviceTcpServer.sock);
            this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));
            continue;
        }

        break;

    }


    cout << "Socket init done \n";
}

void tcp_user_accept_task() {

    while ( finish_app == false ) {
        int temp_sck = -1;
        temp_sck = accept(_serviceTcpServer.sock, (sockaddr *) &_serviceTcpServer.remoteAddr, &_serviceTcpServer.sockLen);
        if ( temp_sck == -1 ) {
            this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(2));
            continue;
        }
        TcpClient tcpClient;
        tcpClient.clientAddr = _serviceTcpServer.remoteAddr.sin_addr;
        tcpClient.clientSocket = temp_sck;
        TcpClients.push_back( tcpClient );
        cout << "... New connection request: " << temp_sck << endl;
        ++_serviceTcpServer.connectedClient;
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(50));
    }
}


uint8_t temp_recv[100];
void tcp_server_run() {

    while ( finish_app == false ) {

        for(uint16_t i = 0 ; i < _serviceTcpServer.connectedClient; i++ ) {
            int temp_cs = TcpClients[i].clientSocket;
            fcntl(temp_cs, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);
            int temp_recvLen  = recv(temp_cs, temp_recv, 20, 0);
            if( temp_recvLen > 0 ) {
                time_t _time = chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(chrono::system_clock::now());
                cout << "Message Received At:" << ctime(&_time) << "   :";
                cout << temp_recv << endl;
                break;
            } else {
                this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(10));
            }
        }

        if ( temp_recv[0] == 'q' ) {
            finish_app = true;
        }
    }

    close(_serviceTcpServer.sock);
}




int main() {

    thread init_thread(init_tcp_server_socket);
    init_thread.join();
    thread accept_thread(tcp_user_accept_task);
    thread run_thread(tcp_server_run);
    accept_thread.join();
    run_thread.join();

    return 0;
}
```

But the problem is about 3-4 packets received in only 1 second as in the screen image.

[image]

Note: 
When the code `this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(10));` commented, the problem was solved. But since the processor is not sleep, the processor is working at 100%.
When the client is accepted, I added 10 us timeout to client recv with the code below and comment and `fcntl(temp_cs, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);`

```
struct timeval _timeval;
_timeval.tv_sec = 0;
_timeval.tv_usec = 10;
setsockopt(tcpClient.clientSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (const char*) &_timeval, sizeof(_timeval));
```

The problem continues as in "this_thread::sleep_for".

Comment: Unsure whether it is related, but I can see that this code uses non blocking sockets and active loops. Why do not you use simply blocking sockets?

Comment: @SergeBallesta Non-blocking works with "fcntl(temp_cs, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);". Because I shouldn't wait any client to send data. 
I need to get and process whichever client sends data.

Comment: Off topic but... you have mutable globals such as `TcpClients` being accessed simultaneously from multiple threads (`tcp_user_accept_task` and `tcp_server_run`).  That's undefined behaviour.

Comment: @G.M. Because of both the simplicity of the code and the newly written, the edits you specified were not added.

Comment: ...and why the call to `sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(10))` in `tcp_server_run` if `recv` returns `< 0` on a given connection?  Why sleep instead of simply moving on to the next connection?

Comment: @G.M.  I want to prevent the processor from working too much by sleeping Thread.

Comment: @QweQwe you understand that sleeping doesn't just block processor time; it blocks **IO** on that thread too (i.e. handling another connection), right? Generally the last thing in the world you want an IO-bound server to do is sleep on *anything*.Its there to do work, and so are your cores. That's why you paid for them.

Comment: Then -- as hinted at by @SergeBallesta -- you would be far better off using blocking sockets along with something like [`select`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) or [`epoll`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/epoll.7.html) (or perhaps even [`boost.asio`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html).  Otherwise you're going to end up writing a busy-waiting loop.

Comment: @QweQwe If `recv()` returns zero you should close the socket, and if it returns < 0 you should close the socket unless it was a read timeout, which it can't be in non-blocking mode, so again you should close the socket. Instead of just sleeping in both cases. It won't be any different next time. This is where your time is going. Sleeps in networking code are literally just a waste of time. This code has just about everything wrong with it that could be possibly be imagined, including  socket leaks. Read a networking tutorial. A good one.

Comment: Well, you are trying hard not to use the common practices. I think I have never used non blocking sockets, and I cannot imaging using that for such a simple problem. Using blocking sockets would allow you to get rid of all those `sleep` calls which again should never be used in networking. Only my advice, but you should follow the common uses first, and only when it works and only if you have performances problems try to tweak the code.

Comment: The problem is solved by commenting "this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(10));"

Comment: The problems are *masked* by that change. Now you're in a spin loop at end of stream or on a connectionn reset, and you still have several socket leaks. Do read what you're told here. Otherwise what's the point in posting?

Comment: @user207421 This is the first time I have heard about the concept of socket leak. Where can the above code do socket leak? Writing with thread?

Comment: Every time you create a socket and don't close it you are leaking a socket. There is a leak in the socket/bind/listen loop when there is any error, and there is another one in the read loop, where you aren't closing the socket when `recv()` returns <= 0.

Answer (score 1):

You should receive the socket simultaneously rather than querying every socket and sleeping for 10ms each time data is not yet ready.

The proper way to do it depends on the platform

- posix - select
- linux - poll, epoll, io_submit
- windows - I/O Completion Ports

Usually, select which is a posix standard, will be sufficient for your needs.
If you want multiplatform you might also want to explorer 3rd party libraries such as **libevent** and **libev** which already wraps theses platform depent calls for you.

Happy Coding!